# UI gets stuck on iOS 7 while dismissing an Alert displayed from didSelectRowAtIndexPath on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uialertview

I have a piece of code that, when a row in a table view is selected, will display an alert and wait until that alert is dismissed. While it works fine on iPads with iOS 5 and 6, on iOS 7 it gets stuck while trying to dismiss the alert.

To illustrate the issue I created a simple master-detail app and created a simple MyAlert class that extends UIAlertView and conforms to UIAlertViewDelegate:

```
@interface MyAlert : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    volatile BOOL completed;
    UIAlertView * alert;
}

- (void) showAndWaitUntilDone:(NSString*)message;
```

@end

MyAlert.m:

```
@implementation MyAlert

- (void) showAndWaitUntilDone:(NSString*)message
{
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                         message:message
                                        delegate:nil
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                               otherButtonTitles:@"Other", nil];

    if (alert)
    {
        alert.delegate = self;
        [self showAndWaitUnitlDone];
    }
}

- (void) showAndWaitUnitlDone
{
    completed = NO;
    [alert show];
    while (!completed)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                 beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    completed = YES;
}

@end
```

I then display the alert in my ViewController like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [MyAlert showAndWaitUntilDone:@"test msg"];
}
```

The effect:
[image: UIAlertView stuck on iOS 7]

Like mentioned before, this works OK on iOS 5 and 6.

If I don't block the main thread, everything seems to work OK, however, if I run this code e.g. from UIButton callback it works like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in iOS 7 which causes that UIAlertView delegate will never be called once the RunLoop is started. It acts exactly the same when the thread waiting for the UIAlertView is not the main thread. People suggest using UIAlertView with blocks or writing a custom Alert View.

For more details see Apple's developer forum thread: https://devforums.apple.com/message/887792

Comment: Just want to confirm whether any solution is there to resolve this?

Comment: Not that I know of, I ended up refactoring this part of my app. I wrote an UIAlertView+AlertCallback category with showAndDoAfterDismissed method which takes a block of code to invoke after the alter is dismissed.

Comment: How do i get phone out of this state?

Comment: i did solved this problem by calling the alert containing method in thread like [self performSelector:@selector(delayedMehtod:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.5];

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's just me, but this seems like bad design in the first place.  You're locking up the main thread for an unknown length of time.
Why not simply have the didSelectRowAtIndexPath display the alert, and have the alert callback (alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:) do the remaining work you were waiting on (or call a function which will do it)?  If need be, use a variable to store which entry was tapped... This would prevent the negative aspects of tying up the main thread while still giving what appears to be your desired effect.

It wouldn't surprise me if apple implemented something that prevents app designers from locking up the main thread (which is why your code will only work if waitUntilDone: is set to NO, essentially putting the code on an async call).

Comment: waitUntilDone: YES works fine if not invoked from didSelectRowAtIndexPath - when called from e.g. a button event, works like a charm, so it's not that blocking main thread cannot be done. I work with legacy code and moving the code that is invoked later (after showing the alert) would be problematic, that's why I avoided refactoring this and moving towards events.

Comment: @wtekiela still a terrible design you shoud avoid at all cos. Cant see one reason why a wait should be used.

Comment: Agree with above. This design is awful. If I saw this code during a code review, it would not go well for the developer.